# concentrate 2 lists in python based on a shared substring

Tags: python

I have two lists, for example they look something like this:

```
list1 = ["Time1Person001", "Time1Person002", "Time1Person003", "Time1Person004", "Time1Person005"]
list2 = ["Time2Person001", "Time2Person003", "Time2Person004", "Time2Person007"]
```

I want to create a third list that contains only strings that share a substring of the last 3 charachters, so the output should be:

```
list3 = ["Time1Person001", "Time1Person003", "Time1Person004", "Time2Person001", "Time2Person003", "Time2Person004"]
```

Efficient way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a set of the common endings then filter each list by that set.

```
list1 = ["Time1Person001", "Time1Person002", "Time1Person003", "Time1Person004", "Time1Person005"]
list2 = ["Time2Person001", "Time2Person003", "Time2Person004", "Time2Person007"]
endings = set(v[-3:] for v in list1) & set(v[-3:] for v in list2)
list3 = [v for v in list1+list2 if v[-3:] in endings]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after:

```
list3 = [x for x in list1 for y in list2 if x[-3:] == y[-3:]]
```